# Creating ar displayed on google lens

Tags: augmented-reality, ads, arcore

How to create Ar experience that can be viewed directly through google lens? You just hover the ads (target image) and the AR will run on it like the example image.

I have tried different forums and went through a lot of articles and videos but cant find any information anywhere